# How to process CSV timestamp where milliseconds are separated with comma

Tags: python, csv

CSV line has the following format:

```
timestamp,department,building,gender
2017-09-07 00:00:08,215,management,a,m
```

As you know, the separator is a comma. **The problem is** when iterating through each line and accessing the *gender* value (4 column - `current_line[3]`), I end up accessing the *building* value because *milliseconds* part of a timestamp was devided by comma, too!

To fix that, I iterated through each line and replaced the first `,` with `.` so that now timestamp is a single value.

***But modifying a large csv file this way is time-consuming. Is there any efficient way to avoid this unwanted separation?***

P.S. adding a new title value is unacceptable

Comment: `current_line[4]` will give you the gender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever tool gives you this as output is wrong. If you have commas within a column, the tool should place the value inside quotes:

```
timestamp,department,building,gender
"2017-09-07 00:00:08,215",management,a,m
```

Regarding solutions:

a) There's no need to modify the CSV. Simply change the columns definition to

```
timestamp, milliseconds, department, building, gender
```

b) it's not time-consuming to fix large CSVs. Use a Regex to replace

```
search: ([^,]*),(.*)
replace: \1.\2
```

c) Since your tool does not put values in quotes, try a different separator character. Another common one is `;`

Answer (score 0):

Change your `delimiter` to a `|` instead of `,`